# Incompatible types when using recursive generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, incompatibletypeerror

I have written [java code](https://github.com/nielsbasjes/yauaa/blob/aa061aba59937c1197bd23714b6218719edc9b13/analyzer/src/main/java/nl/basjes/parse/useragent/UserAgentAnalyzer.java#L91) where I use a recursive form of generics to achieve a clean way of making a Builder pattern inheritable.

This works but I do not understand some of the warnings and errors I get from the java compiler.

This is the severely simplified version of the part I don't understand:

```
package nl.basjes.test;

public class Foo<X extends Foo<X>> {
  public X doSomething() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

For the "return this;" I get the error

```
Incompatible Types
Required: X
Found   : nl.basjes.test.Foo <X>
```

Now 'this' is always a subclass of Foo (or even Foo itself) and 'X' is defined as `X extends Foo<X>`.
To my knowledge these should be "the same" but apparently they are not.

So in my code I added a cast to the return statement like this:

```
package nl.basjes.test;

public class Foo<X extends Foo<X>> {
  public X doSomething() {
    return (X)this;
  }
}
```

which makes the code compile and work as expected and intended.

I do however still get a warning about "Unchecked cast" for the same reason as above (but now it is just a warning).

```
$ javac -Xlint:unchecked nl/basjes/test/Foo.java 
nl/basjes/test/Foo.java:5: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        return (X)this;
                  ^
  required: X
  found:    Foo<X>
  where X is a type-variable:
    X extends Foo<X> declared in class Foo
1 warning
```

Why doesn't Java see that `X` (which extends `Foo<X>`) and `this` (which extends `Foo<X>`) are compatible?

At this point my best guess is that this has to do with a part of the type erasure that I do not understand yet.

Comment: Consider a `class Bar extends Foo<Bar>` and a `class Other extends Foo<Bar>`. Now do `new Other().doSomething()`. That should return a `Bar`, but with your `return this;` you would get an `Other` back. That's why Java complains. There's no way to express "this type that's being defined" in Java's generic type system.

Comment: In your example it would return and instance of `Other` where a return type of `Bar` is expected. But that should be fine because `Other` is a subclass of `Bar`. What am I missing here?

Comment: `Other` is not a subclass of `Bar`. It's a subclass of `Foo`.

Comment: Yes, I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: And because of the type erasure you cannot do this either : if (this instanceof X) { return (X) this; }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you consider the concrete type arguments, it becomes easier to see the problem:

Suppose

```
Foo<Bar> barFoo = ...;
```

When you call `barFoo.doSomething()`, you expect to get a `Bar` object:

```
Bar bar = barFoo.doSomething()
```

However, your actual implementation:

```
public X doSomething() {
  return this;
}
```

Can roughly be filled with the following concrete parameters:

```
public Bar doSomething() {
  return this; //But "this" is a Foo<Bar>, not a Bar.
}
```

---

Here's a different example to make it even more obvious:

```
class Bar extends Foo<Bar> {
}
class Baz extends Foo<Bar> { //note this is a Foo<Bar>
}
```

And:

```
Baz baz = new Baz();
Bar bar = baz.doSomething();
```

In the above, you expect `baz.doSomething()` to return a `Bar`, but the code in `doSomething()` is returning a `Baz`, but casting it to `Bar`, which has a type safety problem (in fact, these types are incompatible, but you only get a classcastexception when you have different classes as in the last example).